# Jade spacing breaking buttons?

Tags: pug

I'm programming some buttons in Jade, and I'm a little confused as to how spacing works.

The top example functions, but leaves all the buttons too close together.

The second example (with an added space before "`a(href`") completely breaks the link while spacing the buttons properly.

Is Jade that sensitive to spacing? Can anyone tell me whats going on here?

```
div.sub-menu
  div.wrapper
   a(href="#/microsite/a")
    input(type="button", class="button white-button", value="A" )
   a(href="#/microsite/p")
    input(type="button", class="button white-button", value="P" )




div.sub-menu
  div.wrapper
    a(href="#/microsite/a")
    input(type="button", class="button white-button", value="A" )
    a(href="#/microsite/p")
    input(type="button", class="button white-button", value="P" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Jade is that sensitive to spacing. Spacing determines the nesting of each tag.

So, where the following code

```
element
  child
```

would generate this HTML:

```
<element><child></child></element>
```

the code

```
element
child
```

would generate this:

```
<element></element><child></child>
```

which, of course, leads to a completely different result when viewed in a browser.

To add a space in front of each link, you need to insert it by adding it after the parent tag (you could do this for the first link) or [piping](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#pipedtext) it (on a separate line before the second link).

Note that when specifying tag contents / piping text, the actual text content is preceded by a white space. This white space is not outputted. So, in effect, to pipe a white-space you need a `|` character followed by *two* spaces.

E.g.:

```
div.sub-menu
  //- div.wrapper is followed by *two* spaces
  div.wrapper  
   a(href="#/microsite/a")
    input(type="button", class="button white-button", value="A" )
   //- The | is followed by *two* spaces
   |  
   a(href="#/microsite/p")
    input(type="button", class="button white-button", value="P" )
```

Of course, if the result is not satisfactory you can also increase spacing using CSS [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/padding) and [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "pretty" option in jade? If you do, turn it off, because whitespace in HTML is pretty much unreliable.

Comment: Where do I turn that off at?

Comment: Hmmm... it's not the default, and if you didn't turn it on, then it's probably not an issue. Nevermind then.